# Eclipse Juno : unassigned closeable value

Tags: java, eclipse

I am wondering why I get this warning with the new eclipse Juno despite I think I correctly closed everything. Could you please tell me why I get this warning in the following piece of code?

```
public static boolean copyFile(String fileSource, String fileDestination)
{
    try
    {
        // Create channel on the source (the line below generates a warning unassigned closeable value) 
        FileChannel srcChannel = new FileInputStream(fileSource).getChannel(); 

        // Create channel on the destination (the line below generates a warning unassigned closeable value)
        FileChannel dstChannel = new FileOutputStream(fileDestination).getChannel();

        // Copy file contents from source to destination
        dstChannel.transferFrom(srcChannel, 0, srcChannel.size());

        // Close the channels
        srcChannel.close();
        dstChannel.close();

        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return false;
    } 
 }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

IF you're running on Java 7, you can use the new try-with-resources blocks like so, and your streams will be automatically closed:

```
public static boolean copyFile(String fileSource, String fileDestination)
{
    try(
      FileInputStream srcStream = new FileInputStream(fileSource); 
      FileOutputStream dstStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDestination) )
    {
        dstStream.getChannel().transferFrom(srcStream.getChannel(), 0, srcStream.getChannel().size());
        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return false;
    } 
}
```

You won't need to explicitly close the underlying channels. However if you're not using Java 7, you should write the code in a cumbersome old way, with finally blocks:

```
public static boolean copyFile(String fileSource, String fileDestination)
{
    FileInputStream srcStream=null;
    FileOutputStream dstStream=null;
    try {
      srcStream = new FileInputStream(fileSource); 
      dstStream = new FileOutputStream(fileDestination)
      dstStream.getChannel().transferFrom(srcStream.getChannel(), 0, srcStream.getChannel().size());
        return true;
    }
    catch (IOException e)
    {
        return false;
    } finally {
      try { srcStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
      try { dstStream.close(); } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

See how much better the Java 7 version is :)

Comment: This works but I would like to now how to remove this warning without using this feature! And why is it not possible to declare directly the FileChannel in the resources. EDIT : you just answered my question but why don't you close the fileChannel?

Comment: When you close the stream, it will close the channel. You don't need to explicitly close it.

Comment: I totally missed that (for the java7 code) the declaration of the new FileInputStream and OutputStream happens before opening the brackets for the try{}. I guess you mentioned that by calling them a try-with-resources block. After correcting this the warnings disappeared. Love it!

Answer (score 4):

You should always close in `finally` because if an exception rise, you won't close the resources.

```
FileChannel srcChannel = null
try {
   srcChannel = xxx;
} finally {
  if (srcChannel != null) {
    srcChannel.close();
  }
}
```

---

Note: even if you put a return in the `catch` block, the `finally` block will be done.

Comment: With that solution I get an unhandled IOexception!

Answer (score 3):

eclipse is warning you about the `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` that you can no longer reference.